# Erro na validação do campo

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
package br.com.pokemax.modelo;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name = "geracao")
public class Geracao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente letras")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "Máximo de 20 caracteres permitidos.")
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente números")
    private Integer numero;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "geracao", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Habilidade> habilidades;

    public Geracao() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public Collection<Habilidade> getHabilidades() {
        return habilidades;
    }

    public void setHabilidades(Collection<Habilidade> habilidades) {
        this.habilidades = habilidades;
    }

}
```

Minha página xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="pesquisa" rendered="#{geracaomb.geracao == null}">
            <p:panel header="#{msg['geracao']}">
                <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                    closable="true" />
                <h:panelGrid id="camposPesquisa" columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['nome']}: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{geracaomb.arg}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid id="botoes" columns="2" styleClass="botoesCrud">
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{geracaomb.pesquisar}"
                        value="#{msg['pesquisar']}" ajax="false"
                        update="cadastro,pesquisa" />
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{geracaomb.novo}"
                        value="#{msg['novo']}" ajax="false" update="cadastro"
                        styleClass="separadorBotoes" />
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:dataTable id="tabela" var="linha" value="#{geracaomb.lista}"
                    paginator="true" rows="10" rendered="#{not empty geracaomb.lista}" paginatorPosition="top">
                    <p:column styleClass="botoesGrid">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                            action="#{geracaomb.editar(linha.id)}" process="@this"
                            update="cadastro,pesquisa" ajax="false" />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                            action="#{geracaomb.excluir(linha)}" ajax="true" process="@this">
                            <p:confirm header="#{msg['cabecalho.apagar.registro']}"
                                message="#{msg['apagar.registro']}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="exploud"
                            hideEffect="fade">
                            <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button"
                                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button"
                                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                        </p:confirmDialog>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['nome']}" sortBy="#{linha.nome}"
                        style="width:12%;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{linha.nome}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['efeito']}" sortBy="#{linha.numero}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{linha.numero}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="cadastro" rendered="#{geracaomb.geracao != null}">
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                closable="true" />
            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{geracaomb.geracao.id == null ? msg['cadastrando.geracao'] : msg['atualizando.geracao']}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:panelGrid id="informacoesCadastro" columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['nome']}" />
                    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{geracaomb.geracao.nome}" size="20" />
                    <p:message for="nome" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['numero']} " rendered="true" />
                    <p:inputText id="numero" value="#{geracaomb.geracao.numero}" />
                    <p:message for="numero" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="botoesCrud">
                    <p:commandButton action="#{geracaomb.gravar}"
                        value="#{msg['salvar']}" update="cadastro" />
                    <p:commandButton action="#{geracaomb.cancelar}"
                        value="#{msg['cancelar']}"
                        update="cadastro,pesquisa,:pesquisa:tabela" immediate="true"
                        ajax="false" styleClass="separadorBotoes" />
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{geracaomb.novo}"
                        value="#{msg['novo']}" ajax="false"
                        rendered="#{geracaomb.geracao.id != null}"
                        styleClass="separadorBotoes" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

E o meu método gravar:

```
public void gravar() {
        try {
            if (geracao.getId() == null) {
                dao.insert(geracao);
                MensagensUtil.sucesso("Geração " + geracao.getNome() + " cadastrado(a) com sucesso!");
                geracao = new Geracao();
            } else {
                dao.update(geracao);
                MensagensUtil.sucesso("Geração " + geracao.getNome() + " atualizado(a) com sucesso!");
                // lista = dao.findByName(arg);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            MensagensUtil.erro(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

    }
```

Quando eu tento fazer um novo cadastro não acontece nada na tela e no meu log tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> 17:52:52,620 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-4)
>   javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could
>   be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern'
>   validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'numero'
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:229)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:310)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:244)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:163)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:116)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:617)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:1074)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1042)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:957)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:905)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:239)
>     at
>   javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:316)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1164)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:982)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:299)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Alguém sabe onde está meu erro e podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Veja isso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu erro é simples. Veja na sua entidade:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]*", message = "Atenção, digite somente números")
private Integer numero;
```

A anotação `@Pattern` não deve ser usada em campos do tipo `Integer`. O motivo é porque não faz sentido. Não há como o seu `Integer` ter algo que não seja número que possa disparar essa sua mensagem de validação.

Portanto, a solução seria uma das seguintes:

- Retire a anotação `@Pattern`. Se quiser, use as anotações `@Max` e/ou `@Min` para delimitar os números desejados, tal como esse exemplo:

  ```
  @Min(value = 1, message = "Atenção, digite somente números de 1 a 721")
  @Max(value = 721, message = "Atenção, digite somente números de 1 a 721")
  private Integer numero;
  ```
- Mude o tipo do campo, bem como o getter e setter para `String`.

Além disso, a anotação `@NotBlank` também não pode ser usada em campos do tipo `Integer`. Então se você preferir a primeira opção, remova-a também.

Comment: Descobri isso dando uma pesquisada mais afundo, mas foi exatamente isso. Muito obrigado.